# How to connect to angular, nodejs http://localhost:4200 in google chrome

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, cmd

I am following the tutorial from https://angular.io/cli, but i am unable to connect to http://localhost:4200 after using the command `ng serve` from my command prompt.

```
The page returned the following error: This site can’t provide a secure connection, ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The project is compiled successfully
```

- I had tried allowing nodejs.exe and chrome.exe to in firewall
- I disabled the Proxy Server From the (Settings -> Advance Settings -> Open Proxy Settings -> LAN settings)
- I tried telnet cmd>telnet localhost 4200 (successful)
- I tried connecting from internet explorer, it worked but there is no content in the webpage.

The following are executed within the windows command prompt following the tutorial:

```
C:\Users\Ufinity\Desktop\test-angular>ng serve

10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 49.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.71 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.08 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-09-05T09:55:54.613Z - Hash: 2c73ac9786af94e810bc - Time: 10587ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I should be able to connect to http://localhost:4200 and the page should display a welcome to test-angular page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Solution 1: Use incognito google chrome to go to http://localhost:4200
2. Solution 2: Make sure you are not connected to any VPN:

   1. Go to developer tools Chrome 3 dots > More tools > Developer tools
   2. Right click on the refresh button > select > Empty Cache and Hard Reload
   3. Then type http://localhost:4200

[Go to developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RBXq.png)

[Empty cache and hard reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFbh4.png)

[Enter http://localhost:4200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIp5U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/'
 in protractor.config.js file